# How can I break an outer loop with PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops, break

I am looking to break an outer for/foreach loop in PHP.

This can be done in ActionScript like so:

```
top : for each(var i:MovieClip in movieClipArray)
{
    for each(var j:String in nameArray)
    {
        if(i.name == j) break top;
    }
}
```

What's the PHP equivalent?

Comment: Always have a look at the documentation first: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: I've posted 2 solutions, one with labels, as in action script and other that just uses `break`

Answer (score 324, accepted):

In the case of 2 nested loops:

```
break 2;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: that goes for `continue 2`,just for more info =)

Answer (score 47):

[**PHP Manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php) says

> break accepts an optional numeric
>   argument which tells it how many
>   nested enclosing structures are to be
>   broken out of.

```
break 2;
```

Answer (score 22):

You can using just a break-n statement:

```
foreach(...)
{
    foreach(...)
    {
        if (i.name == j) 
            break 2; //Breaks 2 levels, so breaks outermost foreach
    }
}
```

If you're in php >= 5.3, you can use labels and `goto`s, similar as in ActionScript:

```
foreach (...)
{        
    foreach (...)
    {
        if (i.name == j) 
            goto top;
    }
}
top:
```

But `goto` must be used carefully. Goto is *evil* (considered bad practice)

Comment: There are quite valid uses for goto. Even eval() is not evil (and it is). It has even less uses than goto.

Comment: Yes. That's why I said "goto must be used carefully"

Comment: In that note I believe this page is relevant: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Answer (score 14):

You can use `break 2;` to break out of two loops at the same time. It's not quite the same as your example with the "named" loops, but it will do the trick.

Answer (score 9):

```
$i = new MovieClip();
foreach ($movieClipArray as $i)
{
    $nameArray = array();
    foreach ($nameArray as $n) 
        if ($i->name == $n) 
            break 2;
}
```

Comment: Nice try at converting the entire supplied code to PHP, though the break statement doesn't do what I need it to do (it only ends the inner loop).

Comment: refresh you page :) I replaced with _break 2_ ... which according to PHP Manual: "break accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of. "

Answer (score 6):

Use goto?

```
for ($i = 0, $j = 50; $i < 100; $i++) 
{
  while ($j--) 
  {
    if ($j == 17) 
      goto end; 
  }  
}
echo "i = $i";
end:
echo 'j hit 17';
```

Comment: I know this is a 10-year-old answer but goto was never the right answer. If it's 2021+ and you are reading this, please, never use goto!

Comment: Even the manual itself warns against it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php