# In Php 'foreach' skip the current iteration block and also rest of the loop

Tags: php

Php 'Continue' will tell it to skip the current iteration block, but continue on with the rest of the loop. Works in all scenerios (for, while, etc.).But I want to skip the rest of the loop.I tried it using break;But not work.

```
if ($column_names > 0) {
    foreach ($column_names as $heading) {
        foreach ($heading as $column_heading)
            if($column_heading == "trip_id"){
                break;
            }
            if($column_heading == "number_of_pessengers"){
                $column_heading = "No. pessengers";
            }
            $cellWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($column_heading);
            $pdf->Cell($cellWidth + 2, 10, $column_heading, 1);
    }
}
```

What's the wrong in my code.

Comment: share some data to test ? do you want to break from outer loop also ?

Comment: `break` only breaks the current loop not the outer one. To break the outer one try `break 2`

Comment: are you sure for the matching  values  ??  try var_dump($column_names)

Comment: Please be specific ,describe your problem, from where $column_name is coming from  ?,which type of data it holds ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `break 2;`

If you want to exit out of nested loops you have to use the "argument" for break.

```
foreach ($column_names as $heading) {
    foreach ($heading as $column_heading)
        if($column_heading == "trip_id"){
            break 2; //break out of both loops.
        }
        if($column_heading == "number_of_pessengers"){
            $column_heading = "No. pessengers";
        }
        $cellWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($column_heading);
        $pdf->Cell($cellWidth + 2, 10, $column_heading, 1);
     }
}
```

Who knew you can put a number with `break`, also `continue` works the same way.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

> **break** ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.
>
> **break** accepts an optional numeric argument which tells it how many nested enclosing structures are to be broken out of. The default value is 1, only the immediate enclosing structure is broken out of.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

If you want to exist from both loop then you have to keep a flag variable

```
if ($column_names > 0) {
foreach ($column_names as $heading) {
  $flag = 0;
    foreach ($heading as $column_heading){
        if($column_heading == "trip_id"){
            $flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        if($column_heading == "number_of_pessengers"){
            $column_heading = "No. pessengers";
        }
        $cellWidth = $pdf->GetStringWidth($column_heading);
        $pdf->Cell($cellWidth + 2, 10, $column_heading, 1);
     }
   if($flag == 1) break;
}
```

or you can use break 2;

you can check here [How can I break an outer loop with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880442/how-can-i-break-an-outer-loop-with-php)