# Break loop from inside loop php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have array like this that i produce using for loops. I want to break the loops, when they have value "AM", How could i do that ?

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => B
    [2] => C
    [3] => D
    [4] => E
    [5] => F
    [6] => G
    [7] => H
    [8] => I
    [9] => J
    [10] => K
    [11] => L
    [12] => M
    [13] => N
    [14] => O
    [15] => P
    [16] => Q
    [17] => R
    [18] => S
    [19] => T
    [20] => U
    [21] => V
    [22] => W
    [23] => X
    [24] => Y
    [25] => Z
    [26] => AA
    [27] => AB
    [28] => AC
    [29] => AD
    [30] => AE
    [31] => AF
    [32] => AG
    [33] => AH
    [34] => AI
    [35] => AJ
    [36] => AK
    [37] => AL
    [38] => AM
    [39] => AN
    [40] => AO
    [41] => AP
    ...
    [726] => ZZ
)
```

This is my syntax

```
$alp = range("A","Z");
$hit = count(range("A","Z"));
for($i=0; $i < count(range("A","Z")); $i++) { 
    for ($i2=0; $i2 < count(range("A","Z")); $i2++) { 

        $alp[$hit++] = $alp[$i].$alp[$i2];
         if($alp[$hit] == "AM"){
            break;
           }

    }
    $hit++;
};
```

I got an error, like undefined offset and such until the end of looping, how could i break all the loop when i break the loop inside a loop ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5880442/how-can-i-break-an-outer-loop-with-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code:

```
 $alp[$hit++] = $alp[$i].$alp[$i2];
 // $hit is already increased.
 // Therefore `$alp[$hit]` does not exist
 if($alp[$hit] == "AM"){
    break;
 }
```

Replace with something like:

```
 $alp[$hit] = $alp[$i].$alp[$i2];
 // $hit is still the same
 if($alp[$hit] == "AM"){
    // `break` will stop inner `for` loop (with $i2)
    break;
    // use `break 2;` to break both `for` loops
 }
 $hit++;
```

Answer (score 1):

You Code

```
 $alp[$hit++] = $alp[$i].$alp[$i2];
 // In $alp array you have any 26 items as per your count.
 // here $hit is 27 and in your $alp there is only 26.
 // so you just need to push the new variables in and then check

 array_push($alp,$alp[$i].$alp[$i2]);

 // Now check `$alp[$hit]`.
 if($alp[$hit] == "AM"){
    break;
 }
```

Try This Code.

```
$alp = range("A","Z");
$hit = count(range("A","Z"));

for($i=0; $i < count(range("A","Z")); $i++) { 
    for ($i2=0; $i2 < count(range("A","Z")); $i2++) { 

        array_push($alp, $alp[$i].$alp[$i2]);

        if($alp[$hit] == "AM"){
            // echo $alp[$hit];
            // Here is the First Break
            break 2; // it breaks all loops;
        }
    }
    $hit++;
};
```

Comment: it didnt break both loop

Comment: Use  `break 2;` instead of `break` inside the second loop.

Comment: still not working, it's loop until `[676] => ZZ`, i want if the `$alp[$hit] == "AM"`, then break, so it's only have 37 key